# How can I get pyinstaller to working on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyinstaller, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16 and installed Python 3.5, also installed pip3 and with pip3 I installed PyInstaller.  I am not able to run PyInstaller. Whenever I type in pyinstaller in the the terminal, I got the below error?  Do I have to add a path? If so, how do I do that?  Thanks

```
pyinstaller: command not found
```

Comment: It very much matter *how* you installed Pyinstaller, what is the exact command you ran?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 already comes with Python 3.5 by default. Why are you installing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to find where pip installed PyInstaller:

```
sudo find / -name pyinstaller
```

Then you can either run it using the full path or add it to your .bashrc file. To add to .bashrc, create the following line or add your path to any existing "export PATH=" line in your .bashrc (found in your home directory):

```
export PATH="/path/to/pyinstaller:$PATH"
```

Save that file and logout/login to have it take effect.

To make the path available to all users, add it to your /etc/environment file (must be sudo edited).

Comment: I found the location of pyinstaller but where do I add the path in the .bashrc file?

Comment: If there isn't already a line that starts with "export PATH=", just add it at the end of the file.