# Unable to install pyinstaller in Ubuntu 16 with Python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, pyinstaller

I have `ubuntu16` which comes with `python3.5` pre installed. I have installed pyinstaller using:

```
sudo pip3 install pyinstaller
```

It ran fine and installed pyinstaller. After that I ran, `pyinstaller` it says command not found.
I also tried installing it like:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyinstaller
```

It ran fine and said requirement already satisfied. But was unable to run pyinstaller.

I then upgraded the pip using `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then reinstalled pyinstaller but this time used `--user` flag:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyinstaller --user
```

After this command it installed pyinstaller along with some other packages too.

Now if I run `pyinstaller` on terminal, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 5, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
ImportError: No module named 'PyInstaller'
```

Running the command `sudo python3 -m pip list` to get all the installed packages, I can see pyinstaller in the list:

`pycurl                        7.43.0`

`pygobject                     3.20.0`

`pyinstaller                   4.0`

`pyinstaller-hooks-contrib     2020.9`

`PyJWT                         1.3.0`

I am really confused as to what I should do in order to successfully install and run `pyinstaller`. Can anyone please help and suggest some good working solutions. Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646379/how-can-i-get-pyinstaller-to-working-on-ubuntu

Comment: @FadiAbuRaid Yes that linked question is different the issue I am having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I have finally managed to run `pyinstaller` on `ubuntu16`.

I am not sure if its the issue with `Ubuntu16` or `python3.5`, but we need to upgrade the python version. So I first installed python3.6 using below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

After the installation, I made sure that running `python3` is invoking the `python3.6` and not `python3.5`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2

sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

After this if you type in python3, it should launch `python3.6`.

Once this is all done, just upgrade pip :

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

after that you can install pyinstaller:

```
sudo pip3 install pyinstaller
```

also run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

otherwise you will get python lib not found error in pyinstaller build

and it will install and work fine.

I think `pyinstaller` is not working with `python3.5` as this python version is also deprecated. So we need to upgrade the python version. So if any one is on `ubuntu16` which has `python3.5` as default, just upgrade your python version.